# How to filter on a list of keys in a Dictionary using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, optimization

I have this dictionary `mappings` declared as a `Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>`.
I also have this method to do stuff on a hashset in the dictionary:

```
public void DoStuff(string key, int iClassId){
    foreach (var classEntry in
             from c in mappings[key]
             where c.StartsWith(iClassId + "(")
             select c)
    {
        DoStuffWithEntry(classEntry);
    }
}

private void DoStuffWithEntry(string classEntry){
    // Do stuff with classEntry here
}
```

In one case, I need to do this on a number of keys in the mappings dictionary, and I was thinking it was better to rewrite and filter on a list of keys instead of calling `DoStuff` for each key to optimise the execution.

Currently I do this:

```
DoStuff("key1", 123);
DoStuff("key2", 123);
DoStuff("key4", 123);
DoStuff("key7", 123);
DoStuff("key11", 123);
```

Logically something like this instead of calling DoStuff for each (FilterOnKeys is not a method - just what I want...):

```
    foreach (var classEntry in
             from c in mappings.FilterOnKeys("key1", "key2", "key4", "key7", "key11")
             where c.StartsWith(iClassId + "(")
             select c)
    {
        DoStuffWithEntry(classEntry);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want:

```
string[] keys = { "key1", "key2", ... }
var query = from key in keys
            from c in mappings[key]
            ...;

foreach (var entry in query)
{
    ...
}
```

(I would personally use a separate variable for the query just for readability - I'm not *too* keen on the declaration bit of a `foreach` loop getting huge.)

Comment: Will this approach perform better than my origianl version, or is it just a matter of "cosmetically" simplifying the expression?

Comment: Cosmetic simplification really. Fundamentally, .NET dictionaries don't allow you to look up multiple keys in one go. If you were using LINQ to SQL or something like that, there could well be better alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using LINQ as per your requirement

```
var temp = eid.Select(i => 
            EmployeeList.ContainsKey(i) 
            ? EmployeeList[i]
            : null
        ).Where(i => i != null).ToList();
```

The Complete C# Source Code is

```
public class Person
{
    public int EmpID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{   
    Dictionary<int, Person> EmployeeList = new Dictionary<int, Person>();
    EmployeeList.Add(1, new Person() {EmpID = 1, Name = "Peter", Department = "Development",Gender = "Male"});
    EmployeeList.Add(2, new Person() {EmpID = 2, Name = "Emma Watson", Department = "Development",Gender = "Female"});
    EmployeeList.Add(3, new Person() {EmpID = 3, Name = "Raj", Department = "Development",Gender = "Male"});
    EmployeeList.Add(4, new Person() {EmpID = 4, Name = "Kaliya", Department = "Development",Gender = "Male"});
    EmployeeList.Add(5, new Person() {EmpID = 5, Name = "Keerthi", Department = "Development",Gender = "Female"});

    List<int> eid = new List<int>() { 1,3 };

    List<Person> SelectedEmployeeList = new List<Person>();

    var temp = eid.Select(i => 
                EmployeeList.ContainsKey(i) 
                ? EmployeeList[i]
                : null
            ).Where(i => i != null).ToList();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could linq your way through mappings
**EDITED** i missed a nesting level, he wants to query hashsets not the whole dictionary

```
public void DoStuff(IEnumerable<string> key, int iClassId)
{
    mappings.Where(i=>key.Contains(i.Key)).ToList().ForEach(obj=>
    {
        foreach (var classEntry in
             from c in obj.Value
             where c.StartsWith(iClassId + "(")
             select c)
        {
            DoStuffWithEntry(classEntry);
        }
}
```

changed `key` parameter and `from c ...` section.

you call it like this

```
string[] keys = new string[]{"key1", "key2", ... , "keyN"};
DoStuff(keys, 123);
```

this should work

Comment: This causes the value of classEntry to be the HashSet contained as Value for the Dictionary - not looping through each value of the HashSet.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use something like this

```
var ids = {1, 2, 3};  
var query = from item in context.items             
where ids.Contains(item.id )             
select item;
```

in your case

```
string[] keys = { "key1", "key2", ... }
 var query = from key in keys             
  where ids.Contains(keys  )             
   select key ;
```